# Applying a filter in Google Analytics - how to verify?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to follow the instructions here in order to to get rid of referral/keyword spam:
https://www.ohow.co/ultimate-guide-to-removing-irrelevant-traffic-in-google-analytics/

This is what I have for the Include in hostname

sqlpracticeproblems\.com|gumroad\.com

In the "apply filter to views", I do have the "all website data" in the selected box.

However, the interface seems to have changed since the instructions were written. I never see the "filter verification" section, and when I look in my reports, specifically Audience\Technology\Network\Hostname, I still see the "not set" host name.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more related to reporting. Please post to Webmasters instead, where non-coding related questions may be more suited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article is a bit out of date.  I just use the inbuilt filtering which is pretty good.

Go to Admin -> View Settings and select the option to filter bot traffic and press save.

[image: Bot filtering in Google Analytics]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is this supposed to work for all types of keyword, referral spam? I turned it on (do I have to do anything else besides just save it?) and see no difference at all, still seeing all my keyword and referral spam in the reports.

Comment: It will start blocking from that point onwards and seems to be pretty robust ( at least for most common spam )